# I want to add list views of Case object to a Change set

Tags: deployment, change-set

I want to add list views of Case object to a Change set,but I didn't find at the time of creating change sets.Is it possible to deploy 'list views' using change sets?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, We can deploy listviews by using Change Set.

Here is complete list of components supported for deployment via change set.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=changesets_about_components.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 4):

List Views are available for change set, but you may find occurences that you do not find the change set you are looking for. I also ran into this limitation today. You might need to manually deploy theses components.

Some of the causes:

1. Check the Filter Criteria of the List View which you are unable to
   add to the Change Set. Confirm that the views are not filtered by a
   Queue. Queues are not a packagable object and any object referencing
   a Queue cannot be moved through Packaging or Change Sets.
2. Check the Visibility of the List View which you are unable to add to
   the Change Set. Confirm it is either Visible to all users (Includes
   partner and customer portal users) or Visible to certain groups of
   users. List View Visible only to me will be not visible in Outbound
   Change Set.

Thanks to @johan Yu for explaination [http://simplysfdc.blogspot.ca/2014/03/salesforce-list-view-not-visible-in.html](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ZZTlAAO)

Also, note that the visibiliy settings of list views are not migrated via changesets. This is another limitation that will slow-down your deployment and another reason why you may opt for a manual configuration. see idea :

[Migrating List View Visibility Settings with Change Sets](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ZZTlAAO)